# Is there any additional requirements to proceed php mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, production-environment

I installed phpmailer in Ubuntu 18.04 like this

`composer require phpmailer/phpmailer`

added these functions like this to `contactForm.php`

```php
<?php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
include './../env.php';

require '../vendor/autoload.php';
require '../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
require '../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
//require '../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/OAuth.php.php';



$mail = new \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
$msg_admin=file_get_contents('../mailTemplates/mailAdmin.html');
$msg_client=file_get_contents('../mailTemplates/mailUser.html');
//$mail = new \PHPMailer;

$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($request_body);

$main_category = $data->main_category;
$user_name = $data->user_name;
$company_name = $data->company_name;
$country_id = $data->country;
$user_address = $data->address;
$email = $data->email;
$contact_no = $data->contact_no;
$description = $data->description;
$headers = '';

<?php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
include './../env.php';

require '../vendor/autoload.php';
require '../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
require '../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
//require '../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/OAuth.php.php';



$mail = new \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
$msg_admin=file_get_contents('../mailTemplates/mailAdmin.html');
$msg_client=file_get_contents('../mailTemplates/mailUser.html');
//$mail = new \PHPMailer;

$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($request_body);

$main_category = $data->main_category;
$user_name = $data->user_name;
$company_name = $data->company_name;
$country_id = $data->country;
$user_address = $data->address;
$email = $data->email;
$contact_no = $data->contact_no;
$description = $data->description;
$headers = '';

if
(empty($main_category) || empty($user_name) || empty($user_address) || empty($country_id) || empty($email) || empty($contact_no) || empty($description)) {
    echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'input' => 'invalid']);
} else {

    //Do insert query
    $sql = " INSERT INTO enquiry
 (main_category,user_name,company_name,country_id ,user_address,email,contact_no ,description ) VALUES
  ('" . $main_category . "','" . $user_name . "','" . $company_name . "','" . $country_id . "','" . $user_address . "','" . $email . "','" . $contact_no . "','" . $description . "')";
    if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo json_encode(['success' => false,'message' => 'Some thing went wrong']);

    } else {
//        echo json_encode(['success' => true,'message' => 'all ok']);

        $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT enquiry.enquiry_id, MainCategory.name,enquiry.main_category FROM enquiry
        LEFT JOIN MainCategory ON MainCategory.category_id=enquiry.main_category
        ORDER BY enquiry.enquiry_id DESC LIMIT 1 ");
        $result =mysqli_fetch_row($query);

        $msg_admin = str_replace('{{enquiry_id}}', $result[0], $msg_admin);
        $msg_admin = str_replace('{{main_category}}', $result[1], $msg_admin);
        $msg_admin = str_replace('{{name}}', $user_name, $msg_admin);
        $msg_admin = str_replace('{{email}}', $email, $msg_admin);
        $msg_admin = str_replace('{{description}}', $description, $msg_admin);
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug =4;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.zoho.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'anton@xpl.com';                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = '*************!';  // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port =587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
        //Recipients
        //Admin
        $mail->setFrom($email,$user_name);
        $mail->addAddress('noreply@xpl.com','xpl');                 // Add a recipient
        $mail->addReplyTo($email,$user_name);
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'xpl Enquiry';
        $mail->MsgHTML($msg_admin);
        $sent=$mail->send();

        $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
        $mail->ClearReplyTos();
        //$mail->ClearSetFrom();

        //client

        $mail->setFrom('enquiry@xpl.com','xpl');
        $mail->addAddress($email,$user_name);
        $mail->addReplyTo('noreply@xpl.com','xpl');               // Add a recipient
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'xpl Enquiry';
        $mail->MsgHTML($msg_client);
        $sent=$mail->send();

        if (!$sent) {
            //   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            echo json_encode( ['success'=>false,'email'=>'Some thing went wrong', $mail->ErrorInfo]);
        } else {

            echo json_encode( ['success'=>true,'email'=>'send success']);
        }

    }
}
```

Mail authenetication and `env.php` are accurate
Mail server - `smtp.zoho.com`

However, when the user submits the form, I can see the above errors:

> The following From address failed: noman@gmail.com : MAIL FROM command failed,,,SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed
>   {"success":false,"email":"Some thing went wrong","0":"The following From address failed: noman@gmail.com : MAIL FROM command failed,,,SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failedSMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed"}2019-10-28 03:22:20 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
>   2019-10-28 03:22:20 Connection: closed

How can I solve this?

Comment: You have way too much going on in this script to be able to say where the problem is. Test *one* thing at a time. Check the input from your form, check your database queries, check your SMTP settings. SMTPDebug = 4 is too verbose; 3 is enough, but it looks like you have not posted your full debug output - that failed `MAIL FROM` should say *why* it fails.

Comment: where can I get to know about my SMTP setting? , that maybe the problem , mail credentials are correct

Answer (score 0):

Try changing  $mail->setFrom($email,$user_name); to `$mail->setFrom("{$email}", "{$user_name}");` and $mail->addReplyTo($email,$user_name); to  `$mail->addReplyTo("{$email}", "{$user_name}");`  and i will suggest that just for now send one mail to check if every thing is functioning properly
  This is my working phpMailer code , though i used google mail server ,

```
  $mail->isSMTP();                     // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                            // TCP port to connect to




   //Recipients 
   $mail->setFrom("{$email}", "{$name}");
   $mail->addAddress('AAAA@XXX.com', 'XXXX');              
   $mail->addReplyTo("{$email}", "{$name}");
```

Comment: I'm getting this error !```
{0: "SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting",…}
0: "SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting"
email: "Some thing went wrong"
success: false
```

Comment: Don't do this. It opens your script to man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: Thanks for your notice I revert it back